# Setting MySQL timezones using mysql_tzinfo_to_sql

Tags: mysql

Cannot get mysql timezones loaded in OSX.

```
mysql> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
-> 
-> 
-> 
->
```

It just gives arrows after pressing enter. What is wrong here?

Comment: Run the command from `Terminal`, not from the `mysql` prompt

Comment: It says "Command not found" in mysql directory. Where should it be run?

Comment: Ok, need to add ./ before the command...